# Can multiple characters create an advantage using teamwork?

Tags: fate-core, helping, create-advantage

The rules on [invoking aspects](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/invoking-compelling-aspects) state:

> You can invoke multiple aspects on a single roll, but you cannot invoke the same aspect multiple times on a single roll.

Does this mean you can only benefit from one character's [create an advantage](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/four-actions#create-an-advantage) action?

Comment: The title and body questions seem kinda unrelated. It might help to specify the scenario and what you want to do.

Comment: @dopplegreener if you want to update it to add that *creating an advantage creates an aspect that can be invoked* for the uninitiated, go for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### It doesn't mean that.

If multiple characters are each using the Create An Advantage action, they're each creating their own free Invocation(s) of one or more Aspects, and with Teamwork, you can Invoke each of them.

Answer (score 7):

## Yes, multiple characters can create an advantage using teamwork

This is covered under [teamwork](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/teamwork).

> Remember that multiple free invocations from the same aspect can stack.

In the example

> Zird and Cynere want to set Landon up for an extremely big hit on Tremendor, the much-feared giant of the Northern Wastes.

> Both Cynere and Zird roll to create an advantage on their turns, resulting in three free invocations on a Flashy Distraction they make from Zird’s magical fireworks (which succeeded to create the advantage) and Cynere’s glancing hits (which succeeded with style to add two more free invocations).

> They pass those to Landon, and on his turn, he uses them all for a gigantic +6 to his attack.

The player is able to invoke all the free invocations created by the other players.

Answer (score 2):

### The immediate benefits of teamwork are usually freely shareable. After that it can get complicated.

> When you succeed at creating an advantage, you "stick" a free invocation onto an aspect. If you succeed with style, you get two invocations. Some of the other actions also give you free boosts.
>
> You also get to stick a free invocation on any consequences you inflict in a conflict.
>
> Free invocations work like normal ones except in two ways: no fate points are exchanged, and **you can stack them with a normal invocation for a better bonus**. So you can use a free invocation and pay a fate point on the same aspect to get a +4 bonus instead of a +2, two rerolls instead of one, or you can add +4 to another character’s roll or increase passive opposition by +4. Or you could split the benefits, getting a reroll and a +2 bonus. **You can also stack multiple free invocations together.**
>
> -- "Free Invocations", *Invoking & Compelling Aspects*, [the Fate SRD](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/invoking-compelling-aspects#free-invocations) (emphasis mine)

You can't pay multiple Fate Points out of your personal supply to hit the same aspect repeatedly on a single roll, but you can cash in any number of free invocations on that roll, whether they're on the same aspect or different ones.

Because free invocations are completely interchangeable when they're on relevant aspects, there are two equally valid ways of "using teamwork to Create an Advantage" that have the same initial result: passing multiple free invocations on for the use of the character making a key roll. They mirror the two valid ways to use Create an Advantage in the first place:

> When you roll to create an advantage, you must specify whether you're creating a new situation aspect or taking advantage of an aspect that's already in place.
>
> -- "Create an Advantage", *Four Actions*, [the Fate SRD](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/four-actions#create-an-advantage)

But outside of those free invocations, there are some important differences.

#### Teamwork on One In-Place Aspect

- whether the first person made a new aspect or reinforced an existing one, followup teammates try to further increase the advantage provided by it
- any situation covered by the initial situation aspect is always covered by the teamwork reinforce
- later teammates probably don't have the same skill pyramid as the one who created the aspect and may not be able to contribute to it as effectively
- after the free invocations run out, characters can only spend one Fate Point on the aspect per roll

#### Teamwork on Multiple Novel Aspects

- teammates will try to create complimentary situation aspects of their own instead of following on to the first person to Create an Advantage
- ties on the roll only create a boost, which doesn't leave an aspect behind after its free invocation is gone
- any situation covered by the initial aspect may not always be covered by the complimentary aspects
- later teammates can make the best possible use of their skill pyramid to create an aspect that suits the situation
- when the free invocations run out, characters can spend one Fate Point per supporting aspect on any future rolls

However, I wouldn't value the ability to channel multiple Fate Points into a roll all that highly. Your initial allotment of Fate Points for the session is something like 5, so spending over half that allotment, 3 or more, on a single roll, isn't going to be a very common occurrence. In a lot of situations, at least one of your personal aspects will also probably apply, and so having multiple created situational aspects to spend on is a luxury that you usually won't be able to afford.

Comment: *You can't pay multiple Fate Points out of your personal supply to hit the same aspect repeatedly on a single roll, but you can cash in any number of free invocations on that roll, whether they're on the same aspect or different ones.* This was the source of my confusion! Thanks!